# Will page.has_content? wait?

Tags: capybara

I'm just wondering if I'm doing

```
click_on('Open')
page.has_content?("foo") 
click_on("Done")
```

Will Capybara know to wait until the page has content 'foo' or it's just going to continue on to click "Done" regardless of the return value for page.has_content?('foo')???

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [code](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/595cd4a89bc5c7873e74a3b05761d27c30cc198a/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L240-L249), I believe that `has_content?` should wait. If I recall correctly, that is what the `synchronize` part is for.

```
def has_text?(*args)
  query = Capybara::Query.new(*args)
  synchronize(query.wait) do
    raise ExpectationNotMet unless text_found?(*args)
  end
  return true
rescue Capybara::ExpectationNotMet
  return false
end
alias_method :has_content?, :has_text?
```

Comment: the code looks like it should be doing that but when I created a scenario in which the page did not have content at all, it failed in the end but it did pass that step page.has_content?. I checked using debugger and page.has_content? returned false but it still managed to pass that step.